# Handle Multiple Access to dll function

Tags: java, c, multithreading, dll, wrapper

doingI have a problem while acessing dll functions with multiple threads .
I am using my own-compilated dll . I call a dll function from java (JNA) with multiple java threads .
The operation I am processing is about images processing . 
With this method I do observe some little frame generation speed loss.
I am wondering if it is because of the thread access to the dll function .

Here is the function I am using :

```
__declspec(dllexport) int iterate(double z_r,double z_i,double c_r,double c_i,double maxIteration){
double tmp;
int i=0;
while(z_r*z_r + z_i*z_i < 4 && i <maxIteration){
    tmp = z_r;
    z_r = z_r*z_r - z_i*z_i + c_r;
    z_i = 2*z_i*tmp + c_i;
    i++;
}
return i;
}
```

Comment: You are observing "some little frame generation speed loss". Compared to what?

Comment: First the function was in full Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably isn't that you are accessing the function from multiple threads, it should be the external access itself. I don't know how big your values for, for example, `maxIteration` are, but it seems to me that this code snippet doesn't run very long, but *often*.

Especially when using JNA there's probably some serious overhead when invoking this method. So you should try to do more work at once, before returning to Java (and invoking the external method again...). This way the performance advantages you *might* have in C could make up for the overhead.

That said, however, it is not sure to say that this method would run faster written in C than written in Java. Without citation at hand at the moment (I will try to find one), I heard in a lecture a few weeks ago that Java is supposed to be amazingly fast when it comes to simple arithmetic operations - and this is the only thing your method does. You should also check if you enabled compiler optimizations when compiling your C library.

**Edit:** This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance#Program_speed) states that Java has a performance for arithmetic operations similar to such programs written in C++. So the performance advantage might be slight and the overhead I mentioned before might decide in the end.

Comment: Oh right I think taht's it indeed I have to make most of the time 10*10^6 times this singlme operation

Comment: maxIteration is most of the time 1000